# Behavior of $\sum_i^n (1-\frac{1}{i})^s$ as a function of $s$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta

I'm interested in behavior of the following sum as a function of $s$

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)^s$$

For $n=1000$ and $s\in (1,10000)$, this seems almost linear on a log-plot ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-sum.nb)), any tips how to model this analytically?

[image]

Comment: Are you interested in $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ or just when $n=1000$?

Comment: I'm interested in $n\in (10^3,10^9)$ and $s\in (0, 10^{10})$, but perhaps $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ would provide a good approximation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are interested in asymptotics.  It seems you are interested in both large $s$ and large $n$. The answer will be different depending on whether $s \ll n$ or $n \ll s$.

*For $s \ll n$:*

Since you are taking an average of an arbitrarily large sum, asymptotically any finite number of terms will not matter. This is enough to assume that $1/i \ll 1$. This allows you to use the approximation

$$(1+x)^s \approx 1+sx$$ which is valid for small $x$.  This is the tangent line approximation.

This gives

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)^s &\approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{s}{i}\right) \\
&= 1 -  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s}{i}
\end{align*}

Now use the further asymptotic approximation for the harmonic series:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} \approx \log n$$

to get

\begin{align*}
1 -  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{s}{i}\right) &\approx 1 -  \frac{s\log n}{n}.
\end{align*}

*For $n \ll s$:*

In this case, assuming we are considering $s$ to be arbitrarily large while $n$ is fixed, we eventually have

$$(1-1/2)^s \ll (1-1/3)^s \ll (1-1/4)^s \ll \cdots \ll (1-1/n)^s.$$

In this case the first $n-1$ terms become negligible and only the last term is dominant.  Then we get

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)^s \approx \frac{1}{n} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^s$$

as $s\rightarrow \infty$.

*For $0 \ll s \approx n$*:

Of this I am not sure.  You may need to specify more carefully the relation between $s$ and $n$.

Comment: Thanks! The "s<<n" approach gives a good match to the initial slope. There's a variant of this problem which only depends on $n$, posted as separate question -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175893/smallest-s-such-that-sum-in-1-frac1is-epsilon

Answer (score 1):

I shall scale $s$ with $n$ and write $s=\alpha n$ with some $\alpha>0$. It will be assumed that $\alpha>0$ is bounded and $n$ is large. First, from the monotonicity properties of the integrand,
\begin{align*}
\int_1^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)^{\alpha n} dx}  \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{i}} \right)^{\alpha n} } & \le \int_1^{n + 1} {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)^{\alpha n} dx} \\ & \le \int_1^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)^{\alpha n} dx}  + \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n + 1}}} \right)^{\alpha n} ,
\end{align*}
i.e.,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{i}} \right)^{\alpha n} }  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\int_1^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)^{\alpha n} dx} .
$$
Now we write
\begin{align*}
&\int_1^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)^{\alpha n} dx}  = \int_{1/n}^1 {\exp \left( { - \alpha n\log \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - t}}} \right)} \right)\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 }}} 
\\ &
 = \int_{1/n}^{1/n^{2/3} } {\exp \left( { - \alpha n\log \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - t}}} \right)} \right)\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 }}}  + \int_{1/n^{2/3} }^1 {\exp \left( { - \alpha n\log \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - t}}} \right)} \right)\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 }}} .
\end{align*}
Here
$$
\int_{1/n^{2/3} }^1 {\exp \left( { - \alpha n\log \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - t}}} \right)} \right)\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 }}}  \le n^{2/3} \exp \left( {\alpha n\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n^{2/3} }}} \right)} \right) \le n^{2/3} e^{ - \alpha n^{1/3} } ,
$$
and
\begin{align*}
& \int_{1/n}^{1/n^{2/3} } {\exp \left( { - \alpha n\log \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - t}}} \right)} \right)\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 }}}  = \int_{1/n}^{1/n^{2/3} } {\exp \left( { - \alpha nt - \alpha n\mathcal{O}(t^2 )} \right)\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 }}} 
\\ & = \int_{1/n}^{1/n^{2/3} } {\exp \left( { - \alpha nt} \right)\frac{{dt}}{{t^2 }}} \left( {1 +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{1/3} }}} \right)} \right) = n\alpha \int_\alpha ^{\alpha n^{1/3} } {e^{ - s} \frac{{ds}}{{s^2 }}} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{1/3} }}} \right)} \right)
\end{align*}
for any fixed $\alpha>0$. Consequently,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\int_1^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)^{\alpha n} dx}  = \alpha \int_\alpha ^{ + \infty } {e^{ - s} \frac{{ds}}{{s^2 }}}  = \alpha \Gamma ( - 1,\alpha )
$$
for any fixed $\alpha>0$. Here $\Gamma(a,z)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function. Finally,
$$\boxed{
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{i}} \right)^{\alpha n} }  = \alpha \Gamma ( - 1,\alpha )
}$$
for any fixed $\alpha>0$. Note that in terms of the exponential integral, $\alpha \Gamma ( - 1,\alpha ) = e^{ - \alpha }  - \alpha E_1 (\alpha )$.

Try to plot, for example,
$$
\frac{1}{{1000}}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{1000} {\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{i}}} \right)^s } \;\; \text{ and } \;\; \frac{s}{{1000}}\Gamma\! \left( { - 1,\frac{s}{{1000}}} \right)
$$
against each other on the range $1\leq s\leq 10000$.

Comment: Indeed, that's remarkably close....quite a simplification from the exact formula for the integral! https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-incomplete-gamma-function.nb

Comment: Now wondering if this generalizes to $i^{p}$ (above formula uses $p=-1$). Related question derived explicit expression for a related (slightly different) version of sum https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4183300/998

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You may give it a try by suitably modifying the argument I gave here.

Comment: Replacing $t=x^{-1}$ with $t=x^{-p}$ and mechanically working through the algebra gave me $\alpha/p \Gamma(-1/p,\alpha)$ which didn't match except for $p=1$, I may be missing some assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Since $\forall 1\leq i\leq n,\forall s\geq0, (1-{1\over i})^s\leq (1-{1\over n})^s$, so  $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)^s\leq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^s=(1-{1\over n})^s$, which is exponential and so will be linear on a log plot. Similarly, $(1-{1\over 2})^s\leq (1-{1\over i})^s$, so $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)^s\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=2}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^s={n-1\over n}({1\over 2})^s$. Since $n$ is a constant, this is also just an exponential, so it must also be linear on a log plot. I believe that, since it is bounded between two functions that are of exponential order, that it also must be exponential order, so it also must be linear on a log plot.

This final assumption may be wrong, but I believe that it at least shows how one could model it well. Using desmos, I found the approximation $\exp(-\frac{s}{n}-\frac{\ln^{2} s}{\ln n})$, which is $O\Big(e^{s\over n}\Big)$ and only differs by about 12 for large $s$.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to analyze

$$
S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac1k\right)^s
$$

Using generalized binomial theorem, we have

$$
S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\left\{1-\frac sk+\mathcal O_s\left(1\over k^2\right)\right\}
$$

Rearranging the terms, we get

$$
S_n=n-s\log n+\mathcal O_s(1)
$$

Consequently we have

$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1k\right)^s=1-{s\log n\over n}+\mathcal O_s\left(\frac1n\right)
$$