# Is this function bounded? $g(n)=t>1\text{ s.t. } \int_1^n (1-i^{-p})^t i^{-p} \, di =\varepsilon$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $p>1,t>1,\varepsilon>0$. Assuming the function below exists, when is it bounded?

$$g(n)=t>1\text{ s.t. } \int_1^n (1-i^{-p} )^t i^{-p} \,di =\varepsilon$$

From simulations I suspect it's bounded for all $p>1$ and $\varepsilon>0$, can this be shown analytically?

For instance, for $p=2$ and $\varepsilon=0.01$ the graph obtained [numerically](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-inverse-integral.nb)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're just asking if $$\lim_{C \to +\infty} \int_1^\infty (1-x^{-p})^Cx^{-p}dx = 0$$ for any fixed $p > 1$. And this is indeed the case, by dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I don't see how this implies what I'm asking. You could have this limit being zero, but as you approach 0, this could require $C$ to grow without bound which would make the function in question unbounded

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Let $t_n = g(n)$. Suppose, for every $C > 1$, there is some $n$ with $t_n > C$. Then $\epsilon = \int_1^n (1-x^{-p})^{t_n}x^{-p}dx \le \int_1^n (1-x^{-p})^Cx^{-p}dx \le \int_1^\infty (1-x^{-p})^C x^{-p}dx$, which is a contradiction if $C$ is big enough. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, the limit logic makes sense now....could you elaborate how you obtained that the limit is 0? I'm expecting this to not hold for p=1, so wondering where p>1 condition gets used

Comment: It looks like limit going to 0 also follows from @Claude Leibovici calculation

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Fix $p > 1$. You can bound $|(1-x^{-p})^C x^{-p}| \le x^{-p}$ for each $x,C$. Since $x^{-p}$ is integrable (over $[1,\infty)$), the dominated convergence theorem applies. Since $\lim_{C \to +\infty} (1-x^{-p})^C x^{-p} = 0$ for any $x \in [1,\infty)$, we see that $\lim_{C \to +\infty} \int_1^\infty (1-x^{-p})^Cx^{-p}dx = \int_1^\infty 0 dx = 0$.

Comment: do you think this holds more generally? Instead of $i^{-p}$ use $f(i)$ where $\int_1^n f(i) di<c$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov yea, and the proof works

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

I repeated the calculations for the general case and found that, if
$$I_p=\int_1^n \left(1-i^{-p}\right)^t \,i^{-p}\, di$$
$$(p-1)\,I_p=\frac{\Gamma \left(2-\frac{1}{p}\right) \Gamma (t+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(t-\frac{1}{p}+2\right)}-n^{1-p} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{p-1}{p},-t;2-\frac{1}{p};n^{-p}\right)$$ So, for $p=2$
$$I_2=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (t+1)}{2 \Gamma \left(t+\frac{3}{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{n}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-t;\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ while your file shows
$$I_2=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma (2 t+1)}{2 \Gamma \left(2 t+\frac{3}{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{n}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},-2 t;\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which does not seem to be the same.

So, at this time, I prefer to not continue until we clarify.

Comment: It looks analogous to me actually - the extra factor of 2 is because the notebook used $2t$ initially. In the question I dropped the factor of $2$ for conciseness since it didn't affect the issue of boundedness